# Can I serialise a mongodb collection with C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have a mongodb collection that I serialize into a `List<BsonDocument>`.

Is there a way to save this list of documents to a file (preferably human readable) using C#?

And then load this file back into a List?

I use this to save copies of a Settings collection so it can be passed to different users.

I can't use mongodb techniques (db.copyDatabase)as the users won't have that level of access

Comment: So each setting is a different *row* in the database and so the list represents a listing of settings?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  Where each document (row) is of a different type. e.g. an e-mail setting document, an ftp server document

Comment: Okay, what does `BsonDocument` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a BsonDocument into a Json string using [`ToJson()`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/f2916ed8-9de5-03cb-45fc-b6bb97477c81.htm)

You can convert a Json string into a BsonDocument using [`BsonDocument.Parse()`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/b7ca6c27-2709-d294-8f83-d223c8cd947b.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Reda's answer I wrote this:  Which works fine

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Saves the current Settings collection to a file
    /// </summary>
    internal void BackupSettings()
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "JSON files (*.json)|*.json";
        saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Beam.NET\Settings backups";
        saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                List<BsonDocument> settingsList = _beamDatabaseClient.GetAllSettings();

                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName, false))
                {
                    foreach (var bsonDocument in settingsList)
                    {
                        var json = bsonDocument.ToJson();
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(json);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to Backup Settings",
                                "Critical Warning",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                MessageBoxIcon.Warning,
                                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                                MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign,
                                true);
            }

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Restores the Settings collection from a file
    /// </summary>
    internal void RestoreSettings()
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "JSON files (*.json)|*.json";
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Beam.NET\Settings backups";
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                _beamDatabaseClient.DeleteSettings();

                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName))
                {
                    string json;
                    while((json = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        var bsonDocument = BsonDocument.Parse(json);

                        _beamDatabaseClient.WriteBSONRecord(Collections.Settings, bsonDocument);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to Restore Settings",
                                "Critical Warning",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                MessageBoxIcon.Warning,
                                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                                MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign,
                                true);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

I haven't included the methods for writing to and from MongoDb but they are just simple read/write